# Hive - Extract arrays from Json

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I have table which contains some **array of values**.

```
create external table apidetails
(
  inputdetails sting
)
Location 'XXXX'
```

`select inputdetails from apidetails`

```
{ "Name": "api-server1", "ID": "api-1", "tags": ["tag-1","tag-2"] }
```

I need the results as

|   ID | tags |

|-------|---------------|

|api-1| tag-1,tag-2|

I tried select json_extract_scalar(inputdetails ,'$tags'), but it returns errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few options:

#### Option 1: JSON

```
select  json_extract_scalar(inputdetails ,'$.ID') as ID
       ,json_extract(inputdetails ,'$.tags')      as tags

from    apidetails
;
```

---

```
  ID   |       tags
-------+-------------------
 api-1 | ["tag-1","tag-2"]
```

#### Option 2: array(varchar)

```
select  json_extract_scalar(inputdetails ,'$.ID')                       as ID
       ,cast(json_extract(inputdetails ,'$.tags') as array(varchar))    as tags

from    apidetails
;
```

---

```
  ID   |      tags
-------+----------------
 api-1 | [tag-1, tag-2]
```

#### Option 3: delimited string

```
select  json_extract_scalar(inputdetails ,'$.ID')                                       as ID
       ,array_join(cast(json_extract(inputdetails ,'$.tags') as array(varchar)),',')    as tags

from    apidetails
;
```

---

```
  ID   |    tags
-------+-------------
 api-1 | tag-1,tag-2
```

Comment: Is this possible to remove '[' and ']' ?